# Shape behavior as it approaches a vertical guideline

Tags: visio

Say I have a vertical guideline and a shape to the left of that guideline.

When I move the shape towards the guideline using arrow keys, the shape jumps back to the left.

How do I prevent this?

I am using Visio Standard 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the snap to guides option. I had it turned on. When I selected multiple shapes and used the arrow key to move them, it would always snap the entire group to the right of the guideline. I'm still not sure about this behavior but I simply turned off the snap to guides feature.

I could not recreate the behavior when I created a new guideline, which really stumped me.